# Xcode Core Data in Tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

my app is in the appstore and after updating to ios 8 and testing the app on my new iphone 6 the app doesnt work correctly.
ive already found the problem: i stored 3 dimensional arrays in nsuserdefaults and its giving me the error:mutating object sent to immutable....
so i can forget to store 3d arrays in nsuserdefaults, because i can`t really change those.

My idea was to store all the data in core data. GREAT!
But i gotta learn!
So....
I have got 5 attributes like you can see on the image:
[image: entities and attributes]

when pushing an add-button all of the 5 attributes get saved by core data in the sqlite file.
The attribute "datum" of type date comes from a datepicker,so i can select a date. the other attributes are hours,minutes and some note - strings.
so, i want to look my tableview like this:

```
2014                <--- sectiontitle with year
   -October         <--- rows cell.text
   -November        <--- rows cell.text

2015                <--- sectiontitle with year
   -January         <--- rows cell.text
   -May             <--- rows cell.text
```

In this example i made entries for october+november in 2014 and january+may in 2015.
This means, this tableview is an overview to all the data,that i want to be filtered in the year and month.
what is the best approach to do this.
is there an easier way than: fetching the date, putting the dates into an array, setting dateformatter and find non-equal dates to get the years and the months?
because, when pushing a cell, for example october in section 0, a detailview opens and i want to display all entries i made in october in 2014.

### What is your advice? Please help!!!

Comment: You should really read up on everything Core Data related. Hint: `NSPredicate` is your friend. Also the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Thank you, after filtering with a predicate i will get the year and/or the month from my date object. But how to associate the attribute vorlagen with the date. How does the string knows its association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user defaults is sufficient for your needs, I'd stick with it but convert the data to something mutable when you read it. You can convert an immutable property list to a mutable one using `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy`. As the name implies, it's a deep copy, and you can have it convert mutable containers and/or leaves to mutable equivalents.

If you read from user defaults into `NSDictionary *userDefaultsData`, convert with

```
NSDictionary *mutableData = CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL, userDefaultsData, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

That will recursively copy the entire thing, converting `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` as it goes.

Comment: Thank you tom! I will try this in the next days! If i understand you correctly, when i use  deepcopy - then i can use the array or dictionary the "normal" way without using [array mutablecopy]; ?

Comment: In appdelegate: this is one of my arrays--->   `stdPickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[def objectForKey:@"gesamtStdArray"]];`  and this is my dictionary for exmple----> `_dict  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:stdPickerArray, @"stdDict",nil];`       [def registerDefaults:_dict];
[def synchronize];      so should i replace my dictionary with the one you said?

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks again Tom**, you saved me from much work!!!

In appdelegate i changed...

```
stdPickerArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[def objectForKey:@"gesamtStdArray"]];
```

to...

```
stdPickerArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[def objectForKey:@"gesamtStdArray"]];
stdPickerArray = CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL, (CFPropertyListRef)stdPickerArray, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));
```

**awesome!!!**